# Machine Learning methods suited for CPU

Tags: machine-learning, hardware

I have a large number of x86_64 cores available to me, but no GPUs or TPUs. Which Machine Learning techniques are suited for execution on a CPU? I would imagine more "statistical learning" techniques rather than "deep learning".

The reason I ask is that I'm interesting in studying some state-of-the art techniques, but I'm in the situation noted above.

Answer (score 1):

With 12 or more CPU cores, you wan work with pretty much any deep learning model.  Only thing that will not work is training with 100k+ images or more than TBs of test.  For such scenarios; you can seed the model with transfer learning.

For example, training a Cat/Dog image classification model (from scratch) takes 2 hours on 6 core i5 (as compared to 30 minutes on GTX 1080ti).